# How to call a function in a function table

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel

I want to call a function in a function table in assembly.

```
void prt(){}
typedef void (*fun)();
fun myfun[] = {prt};
```

then I call prt like the following:

```
int main() {
    __asm__(
        "movl 0, %eax\n\t"
        "call *myfun(, %eax, 4)"
    );
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run it, I get 'segmentation fault". So how should I do to call prt in a function table. 
I get this in linux kernel - 'call _sys_call_table(,%eax,4)' and I want to practise it.

Comment: You need to do `movl $0, %eax` (notice the `$` sign).

Comment: Another question, kernel calls a function - 'call _sys_call_table(,%eax,4)'. But I have to use 'call **myfun(, %eax, 4)'. The question is I have to add a asterisk when calling a absolute address. Why kernel need not?